# Shortcut key for 'change to web' in Add Image dialog

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

I, like several other, use shortcuts a lot and having the Editor with shortcuts is a lovely feature, but I do miss one shortcut.

I tend to use [JING](http://www.techsmith.com/download/jing/default.asp) to do screeshoots of what I'm talking about and it uploads an image to my FTP directly and give me the link URL on the spot, but I like to use the **Insert an image** > **from the web** dialog in order not to ever loose that great screen shoot if I have to move or delete my images...

The link I'm missing is the one to change between *from my computer* and *from the web*.

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (*remember that I already have my link on the clipboard*) I get the Image upload dialog:

[image]

but now, without using the mouse, how can I jump to the **from the web** part so I can paste the link in the input box?

Answer (score 1):

The file selection dialog should be automatically selected when you open the dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, so you can just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>,  <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle to the "from the web" option. Doing so will put focus on the text field where you can paste the URL from the clipboard.

This seems to work correctly for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE at the moment, though Safari (on Windows) and Opera tab to an unexpected field and cause the page to shift instead.

Comment: shift+tab is the default navigation on links, I get that, but it would be nicer to have a direct access key, no?

Comment: Eh, it only saves a single keystroke...so I'm not sure how much value there is in it.